# How to use a template for TextBox of WPF 2010

Tags: xaml, templates

I have a template written in xaml. Can you write how a template is turned on for TextBox?

```
        <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FlashErrorIcon">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>                                 
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.2000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True"                    
                                   ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=controlWithError,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                            <Ellipse DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                             ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=controlWithError, 
                                 Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                             Width="15" Height="15" 
                             Margin="-25,0,0,0"
                             StrokeThickness="1" Fill="IndianRed" >
                                <Ellipse.Stroke>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFA0404" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC9C7C7" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Stroke>
                                <Ellipse.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashErrorIcon}"/>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Ellipse.Triggers>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                            ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=controlWithError, 
                                 Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                            Foreground="White"
                            FontSize="10" 
                            Margin="-15,5,0,0" FontWeight="Bold">!
                        <TextBlock.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashErrorIcon}"/>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </TextBlock.Triggers>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="controlWithError"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

I tried to include in TextBox different ways, but I didn't manage to do it. How to include this template?

```
    <TextBox>?????????What should I write here???????????>
     ?????????What should I write here???????????
    </TextBox>
```

How to turn on the template? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the key `textBoxInError` to your TextBox style:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    ...
    <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        ...
    </Style>
    ...
</Grid.Resources>
```

---

Without that key the Style is handled as default style for TextBox. In that case you would not explicitly reference a Style in your TextBox declaration, and would have to remove the `Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"` part.

---

EDIT: If your Style is contained in a resource dictionary (like `Grid.Resources` in your XAML) and has a Key as shown above (`textBoxInError`), you would use that Style like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        ...
        </Style>
        ...
    </Grid.Resources>
    ...
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried but I caught errors. Can you show how it includes in code of TextBox?

Comment: I added the key and VS said that it is incorrect. Please, show me how it includes in New TextBox:)

Comment: I am sorry but I caught such exception: XamlPArseException happens
“Assignment a value for “System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension”  called exception

Comment: Is that TextBox actually contained in the Grid where you define the Resources? If yes, then the error is perhaps somewhere in your Style. There may be StaticResource usages where the resource is not found because you did not create it or put it into the same resource dictionary.

Comment: like that? <Grid.Resources><TextBox Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" Height="89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,33,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" /></Grid.Resources>   No. When I put TextBox in <Grid.Resources> then I took an error.

Comment: Of course the TextBox should not be contained in the resource dictionary. Please see my edited answer. And check for missing StaticResource references in your Style.

Answer (score 1):

You style has the following deceleration:

This means this style will be applied to **all** textboxs. *Unless* you set a different style yourself.

When you write this:

```
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource FlashErrorIcon}"
     Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" TabIndex="1" Margin="147,145,168,131">
```

You're changing the default style (to the one named `textboxInError` ) ...

So just remove the `Style` attribute from the textbox.

**Another Solution**

If you want to give the style a specific name and not make it the default style, use:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="textBoxInError" >
```

And then your original code will work correctly
e.g.

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" />
```